# How to make 4 triangles out of 4 lines

Tags: geometry

Use any drawing software like Paint or the like to draw 4 triangles using only 4 straight lines! Also, the borders of your drawing don't count ;)

Answer (score 37):

I think you can draw

> **any four straight lines**.
>
>  (As long as **no two of them are parallel** with each other, and all the six **crossing points are distinct** from each other.)

This works, because

> **any three straight lines will always form a triangle**, unless either
>  * some two of the lines don't ever cross (because they are parallel), or
>  * all three lines cross at the same point.

Since you have 4 lines, you can

> choose three of them in 4 separate ways,

so you are guaranteed to always get exactly 4 triangles.

Comment: Nitpick: this seems to assume an infinite space, which Paint is not.

Comment: @Mark to escape the nitpick on a technicality: the puzzle explicitly says that the borders don't count :-)

Comment: I think that means they don't count as edges of the triangle (somehow I can't tag you sorry)

Comment: @Mark I agree 100%, but I'm going to plead the letter of the law :-) (The poster will automatically get a notification of any comment added to their post, so tagging me here isn't necessary, which is also why it doesn't work.)

Comment: @mark you don't need an infinite space (it is never even mentioned in the answer).

Comment: @Mindwin, yeah, if I weren't me, I'd say that the six intersection points were explicitly mentioned in the answer, so they should probably be inside the drawing's boundaries, and that would immediately satisfy all grievances. But where's the fun in that? :-) (And in case it needs saying out aloud: if the lines are "almost, but not quite" parallel, the intersection points can be arbitrarily far from each other, validating Mark's comment.)

Comment: @bass a hint to a possible solution: draw the Star Trek Federation logo but with infinite lines.

Comment: @Mark as an FYI, when commenting on an answer, the answer's author is automatically notified and you don't need to (and can't anyway) tag them.

Answer (score 35):

Here's a solution for 4 triangles with 4 straight lines:

> [image]

Here are the first two triangles:

> [image]

Here's the third triangle:

> [image]

Here's the fourth triangle:

> [image]

In fact,

> I suspect that this will work for any triangle formed of three lines with an additional line, so long as the additional line is not parallel to any of the three other lines nor incident to the vertices of the triangle.

Comment: Regarding the final spoiler block: I don't think it's necessary for the fourth line to cross the triangle. Using your diagram as an example: if you draw the lines forming the smallest triangle first, the fourth line doesn't cross it, but everything still works. (I may have also posted an answer to this effect before reading yours all the way to the end.)

Comment: @Bass Good point, I'll revise my answer to include that point.

Answer (score 21):

> [image: fig]
>
>  My solution to this is as follows:
>  - ABE
>  - DBF
>  - ADC
>  - CEF

Comment: I like this answer best, simple and effective. Live long, and prosper.

Answer (score 12):

> [image: fig]
>
>  The four triangles are:
>  - ABC
>  - ADE
>  - DBM
>  - ECM

Answer (score 0):

> [image: 4 triangles with 4 lines]
>  There are multiple ways to obtain 4 triangles from 4 lines. Here is one way you can obtain. The 4 traingles are ABC, ADE, DCF, BEF.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of [Sarbus' answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/92852/17297)